# Measure of region

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\Omega:=[0,1]^2$, $f(x):=-x+1$ and $g(x):=(x-1)^2$. I am supposed to compute the $L^2$ measure of the area of the region given by $$M:=\{(x,y)\in\Omega\;|\;g(x)\leq y\leq f(x)\}.$$
Can I just compute $$\mathcal{L}^2(M)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)^2dx-\int_{0}^{1}g(x)^2dx$$ in this case, or what is meant by the $L^2$ measure of a region?

Comment: The symbol $L^2$ probably stands for "two-dimensional Lebesgue measure". One usually writes it in script: $\mathcal{L}^2$

Comment: ahhhh ok!! I was really baffled at how this could make any sense! If $\Omega=[-1,1]$ for example. I could accept your answer if you posted it. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol $L^2$ probably stands for "two-dimensional Lebesgue measure". One usually writes it in script: $\mathcal{L}^2$.